# Understanding TensorFlow' conv2d for multiple output channels

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

I'm trying to understand the convolution process better by applying `conv2d` to different inputs. However I get unexpected result by transforming 3x3 matrix from 1 to 2 channels using two 2x2 filters:

```
input = tf.constant([1., 2., 3.,
                     4., 3., 2.,
                     1., 2., 4.],
                    shape=[1, 3, 3, 1], dtype=tf.float32)

filters = tf.constant([[1., 2.,
                        3., 1.],
                       [0., 0.,
                        0., 0.]],
                      shape=[2, 2, 1, 2], dtype=tf.float32)

output = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filters, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output))
```

The result is:

```
[[[[ 7.  4.]
   [11.  7.]]

  [[13. 11.]
   [ 9.  8.]]]]
```

What I expected to see is something like the first output feature map to be the result of convolution (1->1 channel), defined by the first filter, and the second feature map to be zero.

Is this dissonance a result of dimensions' meaning misunderstanding or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify filters as

`[[1., 2.,
   3., 1.],
  [0., 0.,
   0., 0.]]`

(which has a shape of 2, 4)

and then setting the shape as (2, 2, 1, 2), you've implicitly reshaped them as

`array([[[[1., 2.]],
        [[3., 1.]]],
       [[[0., 0.]],
        [[0., 0.]]]])`

If you transpose the out channel axis to the front, so that you can read off both filters, you get

`array([[[1., 3.],
        [0., 0.]],
       [[2., 1.],
        [0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)`

so you can see neither of the filters is actually zero.

Comment: Ah, right, mixed up the dimensions order! The innermost pairs in my initialization contain numbers for both filters, so tensor had to be `[[[1., 0.], [2., 0.]], [[3., 0.], [1., 0.]]]`. It's hard to think in n-dimensions, especially if n>3 :) Thank you for helping!